# Unable to open activity from navigation drawer

Tags: android

I am building an app in which using the navigation drawer the user opens activities, but when using switch case the activities do not open. where as the if statement is working.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggel.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_dataType:
                Intent intent_class = new Intent(Info.this, datatypes_number.class);
                startActivity(intent_class);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_condition:
                Intent intent_condition = new Intent(Info.this, condition_info.class);
                startActivity(intent_condition);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Any exception showing in logcat ?

Comment: just return false intend of return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); And comment if(mToggel.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

Comment: Debug your code. Does `switch`  even getting called ? Cause you have `return true;` already on some condition .

Comment: no the logcat doesn't show any exception !!!

Comment: @VedSarkar Then *debug* the code of *switch* statement ? Check if it is getting called or not.

Comment: the switch case is not being called, tried commenting the if statement too, did not help

Answer (score 0):

because it's not the method to implement to do so, Please implement : 
onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: on your class Implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Comment: and know that onOptionsItemSelected it's for the activity's menu

Comment: Implementing this did not help !

Comment: add this : NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: or u can simply add the NavigationView proposed by Android when lunching an activity, it's clear and detailled, and u can add all the modifications you want, 
hope I had been helpfull =)

Answer (score 0):

To receive callbacks when the user taps a list item in the drawer, implement the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener interface and attach it to your NavigationView by calling setNavigationItemSelectedListener(). For example:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    // For example, swap UI fragments here

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.